# how to see what is inside standard java library methods

Tags: java

I wonder what is inside, such as .setBackground(smth) method
Or simple, System.out.println();
what is inside println method
how is it written

Is there a way to see inside of it
I mean what is going on in the backest stage

And I also wonder classes

I mean image class let's say

how is this class built by java inverters

there are so many questions

Comment: You can just use some website like grepcode to check the implemetation. For example, here is System class http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.0out

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code online in a few places. I quite like http://grepcode.com/ for these purposes. Just search for whichever class you want to see the code for.